# Grunt uglify - Update src after combining files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am combining all my js files for production using `unglify` but after combining them and generating my final `app.min.js` file, how I can update the `script src`?

The index file should have only one `<script>` tag with `app.min.js` but instead its pointing to all sources that I used on develop mode.

```
uglify: {
        options: {
            mangle: false
        },
        all: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dev/assets/js',
                src: ['*.js', '**/*.js'],
                dest: 'prod/assets/js'
            }]
        },
        my_target: {
          files: {
              'prod/js/app.min.js' : ['prod/assets/js/**/*.js']
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the node package ['grunt-processhtml'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml). It will update the source links in your html file.

```
<!-- build:js app.min.js -->
<script src="my/lib/path/lib.js"></script>
<script src="my/deep/development/path/script.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->

<!-- changed to -->
<script src="app.min.js"></script>
```